# Why is this leaflet polyline not showing?

Tags: leaflet

I am a newbie to leaflet. Trying to draw a polyline in a leaflet map. I can see the map but not the polyline, is there something obvious am doing wrong? Following is what I have tried.

```
var map = new L.map('map');
         // create the tile layer with correct attribution
        var osmUrl='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
        var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 20, attribution: osmAttrib}); 

        map.setView( new L.LatLng(36.037794380614635, -78.96096701410059),15);
        map.addLayer(osm);

        const  coords =  [
            [
                -78.936167,
                36.0203309
            ],
            [
                -78.9363688,
                36.0203325
            ],
            [
                -78.9364922,
                36.0203341
            ],
            [
                -78.9366325,
                36.0203357
            ]
        ];

        var polylineOptions = {
               color: 'black',
                weight: 6,
               opacity: 0.9
             };

         var polyline = new L.polyline(coords, polylineOptions).addTo(map);
```

My code is here:
  [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/rkkamath/kdhzvjem/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine; you just have your lat/long swapped in either your `setView` function or your coordinates for your polyline, depending on what you're trying to do. Swapping the coords puts the lines closer to the map's initial position:

```
    const  coords =  [
        [
            36.0203309,
            -78.936167
        ],
        [
            36.0203325,
            -78.9363688
        ],
        [
            36.0203341,
            -78.9364922
        ],
        [
            36.0203357,
            -78.9366325
        ]
    ];
```

This is probably what you were looking for. You have to move the map a bit southeast to find your line. :)

Comment: thanks! That worked, sometimes its the silliest things that keep you running around in circles.

Comment: `map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());` may be helpful to recenter based on the polyline's dimensions.